# Infer values of specific key in object-array

Tags: typescript

I want to write a DataTable class that is very smart

```
export interface ColumnDefinition<?> {
  readonly name: ?;
  title: string;
  align?: 'left' | 'center' | 'right';
  sortable?: boolean;
  hideable?: boolean;
  // ...
}

export interface DataTableOptions<?> {
  readonly columnDefinitions: ColumnDefinition<?>[];
  // ...
}

export class DataTable<?> {
  private readonly columnDefinitions: ReadonlyArray<ColumnDefinition>;

  constructor(options: DataTableOptions<?>) {
    this.columnDefinitions = options.columnDefinitions;
    // ...
  }

  // ...

  public title(columnName: ?): string {
    return this.columnDefinitions.find(({ name }) => name === columnName)?.title ?? '';
  }

  // ...
}
```

I put some `?` in places where I don't know how to provide generic types

The goal is to call the following

```
const table = new DataTable({
  columnDefinitions: [
    { name: 'id', title: 'ID' },
    { name: 'v1', title: 'Value 1' },
    { name: 'v2', title: 'Value 2' }
  ],
  // ...
});
```

Then the table should be typed as follows: `DataTable<'id' | 'v1' | 'v2'>`
*If someone tries to use multiple column definitions with the same name, an error occur*

In addition, some member functions should benefit from it

```
table.title('id'); // 'ID'
table.title('test'); // compile time error
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensuring that we capture the actual names passed in can be easily done. We will capture the column definitions as whole in a tuple type (This will also help us when we try to test for uniqueness)

To capture the type of `columnDefinitions` as a tuple type, we need a type parameter, lets call it `C` with a constraint of `[ColumnDefinition] | ColumnDefinition[]`. The first `[ColumnDefinition]` ensures we get a tuple type, while the `ColumnDefinition[]` ensures we allow a tuple of any type.

To capture the name of each property we need to do a bit more. Firstly `ColumnDefinition` needs a type parameter extending `string` (`interface ColumnDefinition<N extends string>{...}`). This would allow us to write something like `ColumnDefinition<'id'>`

Having the possibility to keep the string literal type for the name in `ColumnDefinition` we need to go back to the constraint of `C`. We now need to specify a type parameter in the constraint.`[ColumnDefinition<string>] | ColumnDefinition<string>[]` would be valid but it will not capture string literal types, it will just infer `string` for all the items in the tuple. To get string literal types we would need an extra type parameter constrained to `string` (This will trigger the compiler to keep string literal types.

So the final definition of `DataTable` would be `class DataTable<C extends [ColumnDefinition<V>] | ColumnDefinition<V>[], V extends string> {... }`

With the `C` type in hand we can type the parameter to `title` relative to `C`. So we could write `title(columnName: C[number]['name']): string`

The uniqueness part is a bit more difficult to guarantee. We will need a recursive conditional type (which have all sorts of warnings attached to them). But it can be done. Below the `IsUnique` type will return `{}` if there are no duplicates or a tuple containing a custom error message which will cause an error when invoking the constructor.

The resulting solution:

```
export interface ColumnDefinition<N extends string> {
    readonly name: N;
    title: string;
    align?: 'left' | 'center' | 'right';
    sortable?: boolean;
    hideable?: boolean;
    // ...
}

export interface DataTableOptions<C extends ColumnDefinition<string>[]> {
    readonly columnDefinitions: C;
    // ...
}

type ColumnName<T> = T extends ColumnDefinition<infer N> ? N : never;
type IsUnique<T extends any[], E = never> = {
    next: ((...a: T) => void) extends ((h: infer H, ...t: infer R) => void) ?
        [ColumnName<H>] extends [E] ? ["Names are not unique", ColumnName<H>, "was found twice"] :
        IsUnique<R, E | ColumnName<H>>: ["NO", T]
    stop: {}
}[T extends [] ? "stop" : "next"];


export class DataTable<C extends [ColumnDefinition<V>] | ColumnDefinition<V>[], V extends string> {
    private readonly columnDefinitions: Readonly<C>;

    constructor(options: DataTableOptions<C>  & IsUnique<C> ) {
        this.columnDefinitions = options.columnDefinitions;
        // ...
    }

    public title(columnName: C[number]['name']): string {
        return this.columnDefinitions.find(({ name }) => name === columnName)?.title ?? '';
    }

    // ...
}

const table = new DataTable({
    columnDefinitions: [
        { name: 'id', title: 'ID' },
        { name: 'v1', title: 'Value 1', align: "right" },
        { name: 'v2', title: 'Value 2', align: "right" }
        // { name: 'id', title: 'ID' }, 
        // Comment the line above to get the error below
        // Type '{ columnDefinitions: [{ name: "id"; title: string; }, { name: "v1"; title: string; }, { name: "v2"; title: string; }, { name: "id"; title: string; }]; }' is not assignable to type '["Names are not unique", "id", "was found twice"]'.(2345)
    ],
    // ...
});
table.title("Id") // err
table.title("id") // ok
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=53&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBASwHY2FAZgQwMbDgYQgBsBXAWyQBFh1kEYEIkAeAOTlFSQBMBnOXjCjIA5gD44AbwCwAKDgK4UYJm5MiATzhJMZYAC44rANxzFcBjCIGBQ0afmLMRBCKQB+QwHJr6GF7gAHzgvXBQ0AOCvYREAC38Hc15oGEwAI2tPODSIYhUkRMVYhG4VDOAsnLzMArNFAHp6uAA6VrkAXzk5UEhYRHCMHDxKTFSAFXTrAHkwBiZeZnwOEC4+AmJyKho6OZZBYSRxAG0AXQkZRwVlVXUtbA2KalokekYkXkN8QoVGlrbZTqyOQwDRgPCEUgUVi6YDMMYSAC8cDGy1W-AhmyeOzezGQ6DQRgk7iMcEMSGAADc0A4QWC4ABJXgAVReAEcSLCUZxgDx+DUNKcADRwACicCR5KpUERUjqCnJK0MAAola1mphDGMAJTiiQUiAlHXc3lwFWxQx4gkACWFapgFqQ+KgcAASjqEXqDdwde45eY4EcMVCYcwrWITqieWsjiKI8SjgAiaF6PnKbQQeAkNkchPCoNIZOwsPChMAd0w-HQECz3AspYQuATEf0fvMjJZCHZsJdwrFwXzhdDYjEhkTrCmueRJz9gggYEMkkB7SOXJWUf4pzgxITs7ACdJcATCpgTYcXVkPRScGwRAr-BG40msKWxuj+axL12zAAauGgutIS2Z5XiYH8xCFOBv0jE19lEc4-TAYQKVGPBrjUJBNGvB4gOxeZDBdFR0M0RYxDPS4sPeIQSGwGBoCVOddg+OAH0wCZyhmRiSIUAAyBlmWzZ8JB1C5-UUGBil4Zp7kAj8QPecU4AYt5JOkzFtk-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-ROWbyqaXSAS1GknzysGlQTelXZ1X5CeBZOxrTtms6aCAAGtzzkIA)

Comment: There is a problem :/ In example when I try to add an align of 'right' in one or more column definitions, I get `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'never'.`

Comment: @Shinigami strange .. let me investigate

Comment: @Shinigami Fixed it, the inference got confused about `h: ColumnDefinition<infer H>`, not sure why. Found an alternative

Answer (score 1):

I believe [type variable generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) is what you are looking for! Simple example of the class that operates on the generic type variable would be:

```
interface Data<T> {
    val: T;
}

class DataTable<T> {
    private data: Data<T>;

    constructor(val: T) {
        this.data = {
            val,
        }
    }
}
```

[ts playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=1&ssl=13&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCJzHAPAFQHzIDeAUMmcgG5wA2AXMjgNzEC%20xxC1cAzt2hnBxwARtQi4CJcsgAOUYFUjIAJgPrpME5qXIIA9iG5goAVwRg9UABRU6DAJREd0smAAWwbgDpVmZAF4nF2DKGgAaZxc2aTYWIA)

You have updated your question, and i am not sure what exactly you are doing anymore 100%, but i think that you want to use type alias, and extend it with type variable like so:

```
type Id = "id";

type IdObject = {
    id: Id,
    title: string
}

type V1 = "v1";

type V1Object = {
    name: V1;
    title: string;
}

type EitherOne = V1Object | IdObject;

interface Data<T extends EitherOne> {
    val: T;
}

class DataTable<T> {
    private data: Data<T>;

    constructor(val: T) {
        this.data = {
            val,
        }
    }
}
```

[ts playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?target=1&ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=29&pc=2#code/C4TwDgpgBAkgJlAvFARASzig3AKB6SWOAeQCMArCAY2CSgG8cpmoMAuIgGiZeDWAA2EDgGdgAJzQA7AOY4AvngLQAagEY6KAG5rsS8KrVlKNOoxZQpAQwC2wqOtwW%20g%202Mmzci-AagBRfgALCHFiKWhkdWNqWgAfImiaXBxpYBCAMysqaAARK2ArAB4AFSgIAA80qTgRfyCQsIgAPgYeZi0rAQ5irzwqASsRWryC4qtSIRKW8xYwSQ60qDh8qw4RouKm5IsqAHspdwBXGl3xAAoOrqhigEpWi2dAtBEAOmWCszaHi0vub%20ZFBZFPIgA)